# How to set specific areas of uiimage to process touch gestures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I'm making a photo hunt style app. I've got a number of X-Rays and I need to set specific areas of the uiimage to process touch events as correct and others as incorrect.

[image: X-ray with correct area circled.]

I understand that I can use the code below to get the tap location in the image view but how do I declare an area on the image view as correct and compare it to the tap location value?

```
 CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.imagePlateA];
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have to programmatically create "regions" and test to see whether or not they're in that region after you get that point. For example:

```
//Get the tap location
CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.imagePlateA];
if ([self checkIfTap:tapLocation inRegionWithCenter:CGPointMake(someX, someY) radius:radius]) {
    //YAY WE'RE WITHIN THE BOUNDS OF A CIRCLE AT POINT (someX, someY)
    //THAT HAS A RADIUS OF radius
}
```

and the method of checkIfTap: inRegionWithCenter: radius: can be defined like this:

```
- (BOOL)checkIfTap:(CGPoint)tapLocation inRegionWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGFloat dx = tapLocation.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy = tapLocation.y - center.y;
    //Pythagorean theorem
    if (sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) < radius) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the correct locations of the image is a CGRect rather than points, you could use `CGRectContainsPoint()`

[CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint)